# Cannot call GCP Vision API

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use GCP Vision to extract text from some files I have. I have already configured my GCP project to use the vision API, and provided permissions to my Gservice account. I am calling the following code:

```
# scan deductions file using Google Cloud Vision API 
import os
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud import storage
from google.protobuf import json_format

bucket_name='cloud-vision-alpha'
path = 'Deductions/Target Deduction.pdf'
# Supported mime_types are: 'application/pdf' and 'image/tiff'
mime_type = 'application/pdf'

path_dir, filename = os.path.split(path)
result_blob_basename = filename.replace('.pdf', '').replace('.PDF', '')
result_blob_name = result_blob_basename + '/output-1-to-1.json'
result_blob_uri = 'gs://{}/{}/'.format(bucket_name, result_blob_basename)
input_blob_uri = 'gs://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, filename)

# Upload file to gcloud if it doesn't exist yet
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
if bucket.get_blob(filename) is None:
    blob = bucket.blob(filename)
    blob.upload_from_filename(path)

# See if result already exists
# TODO: upload as hash, not filename
result_blob = bucket.get_blob(result_blob_name)
if result_blob is None:
    # How many pages should be grouped into each json output file.
    batch_size = 10

    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    feature = vision.types.Feature(type=vision.enums.Feature.Type.DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION)

    gcs_source = vision.types.GcsSource(uri=input_blob_uri)
    input_config = vision.types.InputConfig(gcs_source=gcs_source, mime_type=mime_type)

    gcs_destination = vision.types.GcsDestination(uri=result_blob_uri)
    output_config = vision.types.OutputConfig(
        gcs_destination=gcs_destination, batch_size=batch_size
    )

    async_request = vision.types.AsyncAnnotateFileRequest(
        features=[feature], input_config=input_config, output_config=output_config
    )

    operation = client.async_batch_annotate_files(requests=[async_request])

    print('Waiting for the operation to finish.')
    operation.result(timeout=180)

# Get result after OCR is completed
result_blob = bucket.get_blob(result_blob_name)

json_string = result_blob.download_as_string()
response = json_format.Parse(json_string, vision.types.AnnotateFileResponse())

# The actual response for the first page of the input file.
first_page_response = response.responses[0]
annotation = first_page_response.full_text_annotation

print(annotation.text.encode('utf-8'))
```

However, this code fails with the error message:

```
_Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
    details = "Cloud Vision API has not been used in project 563584335869 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/vision.googleapis.com/overview?project=563584335869 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
```

However, it has been at least 24 hours since I activated the API, and I have called it several times using the curl command already. I have attached a screenshot of the vision API console below:

[image]

Why am I unable to call the API? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that the project you enabled the API for is the same project against which you are making an API request?

Comment: Yes, they are the same project.